# Fade Out/In UiView Animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

I am using Swift.

I have a function named fadeButtonsOut that gets called when my game ends. I have an array of UIButtons (tiles) that i want to fadeOut then fadeIn.

The function is:

```
    func fadeButtons(){

        var tileArrayCopy = tileArray

        for index in 0..<tileArrayCopy.count{

            UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, 
                                  delay: 0, 
                                  options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, 
                                  animations: {
                  tileArrayCopy[index].alpha = 0
                  }, completion: { (Bool) -> Void in

                UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5,
                                            animations: {
                    tileArrayCopy[index].alpha = 1
                   }, completion: nil)
          })
     }
}
```

The problem is the fadeOut animation is being overridden by the fadeIn animation. Basically the fadeOut happens instantaneously then the fadeIn animates normally. I put the fadeIn in the completion of the fadeOut so why is this happening? I want the FadeOut to animate then the the fadeIn to animate after the fadeOut has completed.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted seems reasonable, but it's operating on a single entry in an array of views (buttons?)

It uses an instance variable index? I assume you have a loop that calls this method repeatedly?

The handling of the instance variable is probably your problem. Make the function take an int parameter for the index, and rewrite your animation code to use that. Then make your loop pass in the index.

```
func fadeButtonsOut(tileIndex: Int)
{
  UIView.animateWithDuration(
    1.5, 
    delay: 0, 
    options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, 
    animations: 
    {
      tileArrayCopy[tileIndex].alpha = 0
    }, 
    completion: 
    { 
      (Bool) -> Void in
      UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, 
        animations: 
        {
          tileArrayCopy[tileIndex].alpha = 1
        }, 
        completion: nil)
    })
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
for tileIndex in 1..tileArrayCopy.count
{
  fadeButtonsOut(tileIndex)
}
```

BTW, whitespace is your friend. Don't cram 10 tons of code onto a single line. It makes the code very hard to read.

Comment: I have updated the question to provide all the code in the fadeButtonsOut function. Could you please take another look to see where it might be going wrong?

Comment: You need to show how the variable index is defined/changed, and the code that calls your method.